# Carousel multiple: How to make arrows target a specific set of slides?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a portfolio site that contains multiple image sliders on the same page. I had the HTML, CSS & jQuery working for a single slider, but as soon as I added another--with the same classes--things got funky.

My question: how can I make the left & right arrows only target the slides that they are connected to?

```
$('.carousel-right').click(function() {
    $('.item.product').last().insertBefore($('.item.product').first());
})
$('.carousel-left').click(function() {
    $('.item.product').first().insertAfter($('.item.product').last());
})
```

I've tried using the "this" and "each" selectors in different spots, but no luck. I am new at this, so I could have been using them wrong.

```
/*$(".carousels .carousel-right").each(function(){
    $('.carousel-right').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.item.product').last().insertBefore($('.item.product').first());
    });
});*/

    /*$(this).on("click", '.carousel-right', function(){
        $(this).find('.item.product').last().insertBefore($('.item.product').first());
        //$(this).find('.item.product').last().insertBefore(.find('.item.product').first());
        //$(this).find('.item.product').last().insertBefore($('.item.product').first());
    });*/
/*$('.carousel-right').click(function() {
            $(this).find('.item.product').last().insertBefore($('.item.product').first());
        })*/
```

Another problem is that the slider `mousedown`, 'mousemove', `mouseup` when pressing the left button the container moves all the items and it does not work individually as I want it to work like the buttons.

This is my complete code:

```js
var direction_slider = "up";
    var current_step = 0;
    var scroll_product = false;
    var scroll = -1;

$(function(){
    $(".carousels").each(function(){
        var numItems = $(this).find("div.item").length;
        if (numItems <= 4) {
            $(this).find('.nav-btn').css('display','none');
        }
    });

    $('.carousel-right').click(function() {
        //.last().remove()
        $('.item.product').last().insertBefore($('.item.product').first());
    })
    $('.carousel-left').click(function() {
        $('.item.product').first().insertAfter($('.item.product').last());
    })

    // vars for clients list carousel
    var $product_carousel = $('.slider');
    var products = $product_carousel.children().length;
    var product_width = (products * 140); // 140px width for each client item
    $product_carousel.css('width',product_width);

    var rotating = true;
    //var product_speed = 1800;
    //var see_products = setInterval(rotateClients, product_speed);

    $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            rotating = false; // turn off rotation when hovering
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            rotating = true;
        }
    }, '.carousel');

    /*SLIDER CON MOVIMIENTO SLIDER CAROUSEL ANIMADO
  function rotateClients() {
        if(rotating != false) {
            if (direction_slider == "up") {
                rotateClientsUp();
            if (++current_step == $(".slider .item").length) direction_slider = "down";
            } else {
                rotateClientsDown();
                if (--current_step == 0)  direction_slider = "up";
            }
        }
    }

    function rotateClientsUp() {
        var $last   = $('.slider .item:last');
        $last.remove().css("margin-left", "-140px");
        $(".slider").prepend($last);
        $last.animate({ 'margin-left': '0' }, 600);
    }

    function rotateClientsDown() {
        var $first = $('.slider .item:first');
        $first.animate({ 'margin-left': '-140px' }, 600, function() {
            $first.remove().css({ 'margin-left': '0px' });
            $('.slider .item:last').after($first);
        });
    }*/
    $product_carousel.on("mousedown", function(e) {
        scroll_product = true;
        scroll = e.pageX;
        event.preventDefault();
    }).on("mouseup", function(e) {
        scroll_product = false;
        var num = Math.floor(Math.abs(scroll - e.pageX) / 140);
        var dir = scroll - e.pageX < 0 ? "up" : "down";
        for (var x = 0; x < num; x++) {
            var $first = $('.slider .item:first');
            var $last  = $('.slider .item:last');
            if (dir == "up") {
                $last.prependTo(".slider");
            } else {
                $first.appendTo(".slider");
            }
        }
        $(".slider").css("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
    }).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if (scroll_product) {
            $(".slider").css("transform", "translate(" + ( e.pageX - scroll ) +"px, 0)")
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.relative {
  position:relative;
}
.carousels {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.slider {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0.1rem;
    width: 100% !important;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.carousel-left {
    left: 10px;
}
.carousel-right {
    right: 0px;
}
.nav-btn {
    top: 25%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 45px;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #D5D9D9;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(213 217 217 / 50%);
}
.nav-btn:hover {
    background-color: #F7FAFA;
}
.item {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0.5em;
    display: inline-table;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.item.product .c-rating {
    transform: scale(0.6);
}
.item.product .rating {
    margin-bottom: .2rem;
}
.item.product .total-avg span {
    margin-right: .4rem;
    color: #be5a0e;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.item.product .valuations {
    margin-left: 5rem;
    color: #73726c;
}
.item.product .valuations span {
    font-size: .8em;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.thumbnails {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.thumbnails img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.topic-1 .price label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-right: 6px;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.topic-1 .price em {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #17aa1c;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="wrapp">
        <div class="deals">
            <div class="heading mini-title">
                <h2>New Product</h2> <div class="rule"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousels relative">
                <button class="carousel-left nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"><</i></button>
                <button class="carousel-right nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-right">></i></button>
                <div class="carousel">
                    <div class="slider">
                        <div class="item product category-info">
                            <div class="banner-info">
                                <a href="">
                                    <h3>Shopping Guide for Trending Styles</h3>
                                    <img src="https://img.alicdn.com/tfs/TB1ZXXNIgHqK1RjSZFkXXX.WFXa-300-320.jpg" style="width: 320px; height: 300px;">
                                    <span>Source Now</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-8">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 8">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 8</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$2,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-7">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 7">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 7</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$3,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-6">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 6">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 6</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$10,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-5">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 5">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 5</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$45,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div id="wrapp2">
        <div class="deals">
            <div class="carousels relative">
                <button class="carousel-left nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"><</i></button>
                <button class="carousel-right nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-right">></i></button>
                <div id="carousel" class="carousel">
                    <div class="slider">
                        <div class="item ads-store">
                            <div class="adsowners">
                                <a href="">
                                    <h4>¡Oferts!</h4>
                                    <h5>In the store MSShop</h5>
                                    <img src="https://img.joomcdn.net/181508ee57b71b20f26b4a8a14a79f142b9165af_176_176.png">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div id="wrapp3">
        <div class="deals">
            <div class="heading mini-title">
                <h2>New Product</h2> <div class="rule"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousels relative">
                <button class="carousel-left nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"><</i></button>
                <button class="carousel-right nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-right">></i></button>
                <div class="carousel">
                    <div class="slider">
                        <div class="item product category-info">
                            <div class="banner-info">
                                <a href="">
                                    <h3>Shopping Guide for Trending Styles</h3>
                                    <img src="https://img.alicdn.com/tfs/TB1ZXXNIgHqK1RjSZFkXXX.WFXa-300-320.jpg" style="width: 320px; height: 300px;">
                                    <span>Source Now</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-8">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 8">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 8</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$2,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-7">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 7">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 7</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$3,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-6">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 6">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 6</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$10,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-5">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 5">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 5</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$45,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: by looking at your code, it´s very written for 1 carousel instance, like there is unique identifiers `#carousel-right` and so on, if you want to support multiple instance try to work with classes

Comment: Your code seems to have been overly engineered backwards. Start fresh, start with classes . as it is, this is not going to work.

Comment: @johnSmith https://jsfiddle.net/o62fvhLd/ I found this drop-down menu works for multiple menus, applying a number to the end of the id for example: `id="dropdown1` `dropdown2` Can't you use something similar? or just using classes would work?

Comment: @Derple Can't you use something similar? or just using classes would work?

Comment: @Fernando You can use classes, but when you're identifying particular elements (e.g. a single carousel) it's more conventional to give them an ID so they can be selected individually. If you still want to use classes to do this, the best way would be to give each carousel a different class name. But it makes your code harder to read because it's not immediately obvious whether a given class name refers to *many* elements or just *one* element.

Comment: @kmoser Then the most feasible thing is to use `id` to avoid problems, could you help me with that please, it will be that we can do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8anxz6dv/1/, in order to create the` id` with a name and a number at the end, for example `id = "# carousel1"`,`id = "# carousel2"`,`id = "# carousel3"` and so on.

Comment: @kmoser I was also analyzing slider from other sources where there are several slider on the same page I came across this: https://jsfiddle.net/yw7b6z2f/, but I did not understand very well, I comment on it in case it is useful, in that example the individual buttons work for each slider.

Comment: @Fernando IDs should not have `#` or spaces in them, so your code should be: `id="carousel1"`, `id="carousel2"`, etc. The only time you use `#` is when you are using a selector to specify a particular ID, e.g. `$('#carousel1')` to select the element whose ID is "carousel1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your left/right buttons just need to be updated. Also, your second carousel had an unnecessary `id="carousel"`, and the first item was missing the class name `product`, so I added them.

```js
var direction_slider = "up";
    var current_step = 0;
    var scroll_product = false;
    var scroll = -1;

$(function(){
    $(".carousels").each(function(){
        var numItems = $(this).find("div.item").length;
        if (numItems <= 4) {
            $(this).find('.nav-btn').css('display','none');
        }
    });

    $('.carousel-right').click(function() {
        //.last().remove()
        let $product = $(this).next('.carousel').find('.item.product')
        $product.last().insertBefore($product.first());
    })
    $('.carousel-left').click(function() {
        let $product = $(this).next().next('.carousel').find('.item.product');
        $product.first().insertAfter($product.last());
    })

    // vars for clients list carousel
    var $product_carousel = $('.carousel');
    var products = $product_carousel.children().length;
    var product_width = (products * 140); // 140px width for each client item
    $product_carousel.css('width',product_width);

    var rotating = true;
    //var product_speed = 1800;
    //var see_products = setInterval(rotateClients, product_speed);

    $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            rotating = false; // turn off rotation when hovering
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            rotating = true;
        }
    }, '.carousel');

    /*SLIDER CON MOVIMIENTO SLIDER CAROUSEL ANIMADO
  function rotateClients() {
        if(rotating != false) {
            if (direction_slider == "up") {
                rotateClientsUp();
            if (++current_step == $(".slider .item").length) direction_slider = "down";
            } else {
                rotateClientsDown();
                if (--current_step == 0)  direction_slider = "up";
            }
        }
    }

    function rotateClientsUp() {
        var $last   = $('.slider .item:last');
        $last.remove().css("margin-left", "-140px");
        $(".slider").prepend($last);
        $last.animate({ 'margin-left': '0' }, 600);
    }

    function rotateClientsDown() {
        var $first = $('.slider .item:first');
        $first.animate({ 'margin-left': '-140px' }, 600, function() {
            $first.remove().css({ 'margin-left': '0px' });
            $('.slider .item:last').after($first);
        });
    }*/
    $product_carousel.on("mousedown", function(e) {
        scroll_product = true;
        scroll = e.pageX;
        event.preventDefault();
    }).on("mouseup", function(e) {
        scroll_product = false;
        var num = Math.floor(Math.abs(scroll - e.pageX) / 140);
        var dir = scroll - e.pageX < 0 ? "up" : "down";
        for (var x = 0; x < num; x++) {
            var $first = $(this).find('.slider .item:first');
            var $last  = $(this).find('.slider .item:last');
            if (dir == "up") {
                $last.prependTo($(this).find(".slider"));
            } else {
                $first.appendTo($(this).find(".slider"));
            }
        }
        $(this).find(".slider").css("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
    }).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if (scroll_product) {
            $(this).find(".slider").css("transform", "translate(" + ( e.pageX - scroll ) +"px, 0)")
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.relative {
  position:relative;
}
.carousels {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.slider {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0.1rem;
    width: 100% !important;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.carousel-left {
    left: 10px;
}
.carousel-right {
    right: 0px;
}
.nav-btn {
    top: 25%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 45px;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #D5D9D9;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(213 217 217 / 50%);
}
.nav-btn:hover {
    background-color: #F7FAFA;
}
.item {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0.5em;
    display: inline-table;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.item.product .c-rating {
    transform: scale(0.6);
}
.item.product .rating {
    margin-bottom: .2rem;
}
.item.product .total-avg span {
    margin-right: .4rem;
    color: #be5a0e;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.item.product .valuations {
    margin-left: 5rem;
    color: #73726c;
}
.item.product .valuations span {
    font-size: .8em;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.thumbnails {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.thumbnails img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.topic-1 .price label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-right: 6px;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.topic-1 .price em {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #17aa1c;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="wrapp">
        <div class="deals">
            <div class="heading mini-title">
                <h2>New Product</h2> <div class="rule"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousels relative">
                <button class="carousel-left nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"><</i></button>
                <button class="carousel-right nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-right">></i></button>
                <div class="carousel">
                    <div class="slider">
                        <div class="item product category-info">
                            <div class="banner-info">
                                <a href="">
                                    <h3>Shopping Guide for Trending Styles</h3>
                                    <img src="https://img.alicdn.com/tfs/TB1ZXXNIgHqK1RjSZFkXXX.WFXa-300-320.jpg" style="width: 320px; height: 300px;">
                                    <span>Source Now</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-8">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 8">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 8</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$2,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-7">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 7">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 7</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$3,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-6">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 6">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 6</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$10,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-5">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 5">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 5</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$45,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div id="wrapp2">
        <div class="deals">
            <div class="carousels relative">
                <button class="carousel-left nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"><</i></button>
                <button class="carousel-right nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-right">></i></button>
                <div class="carousel">
                    <div class="slider">
                        <div class="item product ads-store">
                            <div class="adsowners">
                                <a href="">
                                    <h4>¡Oferts!</h4>
                                    <h5>In the store MSShop</h5>
                                    <img src="https://img.joomcdn.net/181508ee57b71b20f26b4a8a14a79f142b9165af_176_176.png">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div id="wrapp3">
        <div class="deals">
            <div class="heading mini-title">
                <h2>New Product</h2> <div class="rule"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousels relative">
                <button class="carousel-left nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"><</i></button>
                <button class="carousel-right nav-btn"><i class="icon-arrow-right">></i></button>
                <div class="carousel">
                    <div class="slider">
                        <div class="item product category-info">
                            <div class="banner-info">
                                <a href="">
                                    <h3>Shopping Guide for Trending Styles</h3>
                                    <img src="https://img.alicdn.com/tfs/TB1ZXXNIgHqK1RjSZFkXXX.WFXa-300-320.jpg" style="width: 320px; height: 300px;">
                                    <span>Source Now</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-8">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 8">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 8</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$2,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-7">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 7">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 7</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$3,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-6">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 6">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 6</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$10,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item product">
                            <a href="product/tu-producto-aqui-5">
                                <div class="thumbnails image">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/02NOJHI.jpg" alt="Tú producto aquí 5">
                                </div>
                                <div class="box topic-1">
                                    <div class="heading ellipsis">
                                        <h2>Product 5</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price right">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <em class="item-price">$45,00</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The buttons work perfectly, the only detail is that this carousel also allows me to move from left to right by holding down the left mouse button and when moving the products in that way all the products of all the carousels on the page move.

Comment: @Fernando I've updated my answer so that it works the way you want. The problem was that `$product_carousel` was selecting the `.slider` elements, not the `.carousel` elements, and also the scroll code was using `$('.slider)` which caused all the carousels to be affected. I changed that to `$(this).find(".slider")`, which finds only the carousel that was selected.

Comment: When I move the products in that way, that action remains as locked, it remains active and the products move without having pressed the left button of the maus, that action should only work if I drag or move the products but keeping the left button of the maus pressed. Any suggestions that you can give me to avoid this problem, please? I promise not to disturb anymore: /

Comment: It looks like `scroll_product` isn't being set to `false` when the mouse button is released. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Thanks, I can't understand it either, but I still like what I see, thanks for helping me. Greetings.